# Generating PDF for downloading and opening it in new window

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob, createobjecturl

I want to create a PDF with
`new File(["<body>text<body>"],"application/pdf")`
But I want it without any libs

**With Vanilla Js**

And get base 64 string with  new FileReader
Also tried URL.createObjectURL

it returns a URL but if I open it, after some time it closes automatically
Also, how can I add data to a new file for pdf
Like => new File([data] , ...)

```
const file = new File(['<body>Text</body>'] , "app.pdf")
//Or. 
const file = new File(['<body>Text</body>'] , "app.pdf" , {type: 'application/pdf'})

const D = new FileReader()
D.onload = ()=> {console.log(this.result || D.result)}
D.readAsDataURL(file)
```

Or with blob

```
const file = new File(['<body>Text</body>'] , "app.pdf" )
//Or.
const file = new File(['<body>Text</body>'] , "app.pdf" , {type: "application/pdf"})


URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

Comment: `<body>Text</body>` is not valid PDF.

Comment: I know i already mentioned how can i add data

Comment: adding data to invalid PDF won't make it a valid PDF

Comment: What invalid file ???

Comment: I see both of them but the first one .. what is this about

Comment: Suppose in any html file there is an iframe how to get  base64 url of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write mime type text/pdf i.e. a pdf without binary lib encodings you simply need to write a string like this (save as text.pdf to see how it works)
Or right click & download the demo pdf cmd writer from https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/MAKE-PDF.cmd

```
%PDF-1.1
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1/MediaBox [0 0 594 792]>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica>>>>>>/Contents 4 0 R>>endobj
4 0 obj<</Length 78
>>
stream

BT /F1 18 Tf 036 740 Td (Body) Tj ET
BT /F1 18 Tf 036 720 Td (Text) Tj ET

endstream 
endobj xref
0 5 
0000000000 65535 f
0000000021 00000 n
0000000065 00000 n
0000000139 00000 n
0000000269 00000 n
trailer<</Root 1 0 R /Size 5>>
startxref
401
%%EOF
```

or use in an iFrame

```html
<iframe title="testing" type="application/pdf" width="98%" height="98%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,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">Your browser does not support iFrame</Iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: I didnt get this But for replying i accepted answer..

Comment: One remark, **startxref**, the offset, and **%%EOF** according to spec must be on separate lines. Several PDF processors may be more lenient, though.